# How to use AND condition in Desmos

Tags: graphing-functions, conditional-convergence, desmos

Sorry maybe it's not typical mathematics question, but [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) is very helpful in solving and testing mathematics issues, so maybe anyone could help me.

I can't figure it out how to use AND condition in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

For example to make OR you can just use "comma", like that:

$ y=\{ A<0 \ \ \ \ , \ \ \ \ B>1 :\  f_1(x), \ \ \ \  f_2(x) \} $

But how to make AND? I mean something like that:

$ y=\{ A<0 \ \ \ \ AND \ \ \ \ B>1 : \ f_1(x), \ \ \ \ f_2(x) \} $

But that just doesn't work.

For any help thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a way in desmos to do and function you have to do something called nesting(putting a conditanal in a conditanol) example {{a=5:1}+{b=2:1}=2:f(x)}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't found a built-in conjunction function, so you might find helpful my workaround:

For simple domain restrictions, you can use a product of conditions:
$$y=f(x)\{\text{cond1}\}\{\text{cond2}\}\{\text{cond3}\}$$
$$y=(x^2-x)\left\{x^2>1\right\}\left\{x^4<3\right\}$$
[link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dj7bjwiwip)

For complex piecewise functions, you can use this hack:
$$\text{cond1} = \left(\{\text{subcond1}:1,0\}\{\text{subcond2:1,0}\}\{\text{subcond3:1,0}\}=1\right)$$
$$
y=\left\{\\\color{red}{\left\{x^2>1:1,0\right\}\left\{x^4<3:1,0\right\}=1:\left(x^2-x\right)},\\\color{blue}{\left\{x^2>1.8:1,0\right\}\left\{x^4+x^2<25:1,0\right\}=1:x},\\\color{green}{-1}\right\}$$
[link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gdxlt6pyuz)